# ¿Como enviar un valor desde un CustomDialog a un Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

En el activity_main.xml -> tengo un boton, el cual al presionarlo -> abre un custom list view, en donde al presionar el elemento 1 -> abre un custom alert dialog, -> el cual tiene 2 botones y al presionarlo el Boton A -> ocupa cambiar el texto del EditText que se encuentra en el activity_main.xml usando .setText.
Hasta ahorita no he podido lograr esto, usando diferentes opciones, el principal error que tengo es el NullpointerExeption error porque no encuentra al TextView referenciado, pero quiero saber que otras opciones tengo para lograr esto.
Agradezco cualquier sugerencia!

ViewDialog.java

```
final TextView KMLabel = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.KMlabel);



Button KMPerH = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.KmPerH);
    KMPerH.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, MillesPerHour.class);
            //mActivity.startActivity(intent);

            KMLabel.setText("MLL/H");

        }
    });
```

Comment: al presionar el boton de tu activity, te manda a otra activity? o agregas la lista al activity que ya tienes por medio de codigo?

Comment: y el TextView "KMlabel" en realidad en que layout se encuentra?

Comment: El KMlabel esta en el activity_main layout y yo lo mando a llamar desde una clases la del custom alert dialog @Jorgesys

Comment: No, lo que quiero es que me cambie el texto del TextView que tengo en el activity_main lo del intent lo  olvide poner como comentarios @YorchSircam

Comment: No, aun no, @Andrespengineer

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, y dime si te funciona.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista, tu problema parece estar en como estas definiendo tu variable `activity`. Si estas utilizando tu variable `activity` para castear el `context` del `Dialog` con `getContext()` a `Activity`, te causara un error de casteo ya que los Dialog se maneja con el `ContextThemeWrapper` y puede ocasionarte como resultado:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot
>   be cast to android.app.Activity

Ahora bien, si pudiste pasar tu contexto en un constructor de tu `ViewDialog` y dicho contexto lo casteaste a tu `MainActivity` o como se llame la Actividad ligada a tu Layout `activity_main.xml`:

```
. . .
    private MainActivity activity;

    public ViewDialog(Context context){
        this.activity = (MainActivity)context; // Solo podras hacer esto si tu ViewDialog lo crea la actividad MainActivity, de lo contrario devolvera null
    }
. . .
```

Y aun asi recibes el `null`, debes asegurarte que el id sea el que pertenece a tu root que carga dicha actividad, ya que asi deberia funcionar. Pero aun asi, el problema es el siguiente

La interaccion directa entre la Actividad y un Contexto que esta muy lejano de la misma suele ser un proceso tedioso utilizando `onActivityResult`, por lo que muchos optan por crear una clase `singleton` para la comunicación con una Actividad. Funciona bastante bien, sobre todo cuando intentas obtener un callback desde una Actividad a algún lugar de mi aplicación que no pueda capturar dicho evento de manera "natural", tal como el `onBackPressed`.

Si vas utilizando muchas referencias de tu `Activity` fuera de la misma. En el momento en que cambies dicha referencia, deberás hacer cambios en todos los lados donde utilizaste esas referencias, por lo que tu código no seria muy mantenible o no soportaría **"pequeños"** cambios.

### Utiliza una interface para enviar el valor

Lo recomendable aquí es utilizar una interfaz que comunique tu accion desde tu `Dialog` hasta la Actividad. Si la actividad maneja demasiadas interfaces puedes manejar las interfaces de interacción en una `clase` a parte, y tu `Activity` que implemente las interfaces que crea tu `clase` o capturar la data en `onNewIntent` mediante `Bundles` (para esto necesitas definir ciertas banderas antes de iniciar tu actividad nuevamente).

Un ejemplo de como crear una interfaz e implementarla:

En tu `ViewDialog` haces esto: Defines una interfaz.

```
public interface OnTextViewDataSet{
      void onDataSet(String text);
}
```

Una variable privada:

```
private OnTextViewDataSet listener = null;
```

Y en tu constructor:

```
. . .

public ViewDialog(Context context){
     this.activity = (MainActivity)context; // Solo podras hacer esto si tu ViewDialog lo crea la actividad MainActivity, de lo contrario devolvera null
     if(activity instanceof OnTextViewDataSet)
        this.listener = (OnTextViewDataSet)activity;
}

. . .
```

En tu `onClick` invocas a la interfaz:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String text = "MLL/H";
    if(listener != null)
      listener.onDataSet(text);

}
```

Y en tu `MainActivity` o como se llame la Actividad donde quieras cambiar el texto, implementas la interfaz, ejemplo:

```
public MainActivity extends Activity implements ViewDialog.OnTextViewDataSet
```

Y sobreescribes el metodo de tu interfaz:

```
@Override
public void onDataSet(String text) {
    KMLabel.setText(text);
}
```

Donde `KMLabel` es tu referencia global del `TextView` y no debe ser nula. Asi te aseguras que si algun dia, remueves o cambias la referencia de KMLabel, su Actividad es quien se encargara de hacer los debidos cambios y no tendras que cambiar la referencia en todas las clases donde la utilizaste con un "findViewById" forzado.

Puedes leer mas en la documentacion oficial de la [interaccion con las Activitys](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).

Comment: Claro que si la revisare, muchas gracias por el tiempo! Yo le aviso si funcionó.