# Como pasar una variable String de un popup a la clase quien lo invoco?

Tags: android, android-studio

Necesito saber como pasar una variable String de un popup(es una clase activity) que fue llamado desde otra activity, la idea cuando aprete un boton aceptar en el popup me devuelva a la clase activity sin reiniciarla, si no volviendo a como estaba antes de abrir el popup pero con una variable String adicional. He buscado por varios lados, pero no encuentro que sea de la forma que no se reinicie la activity, ayudenme por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido...Koke!.., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Tienes varias opciones, utilizar una base de datos local o hacerlo mediante interfaces, que es una opcion viable. [Puedes verlo en esta respuesta que hice hace un tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152130/como-enviar-un-valor-desde-un-customdialog-a-un-activity/165802#165802).

Answer (score -1):

Al no ver el codigo, solo puedo sugerirte que uses [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating?hl=es-419)

Basicamente lo que hace es volver a construir tu activity luego de haberla terminado por el ciclo de vida que usa tu app, ya sea por un finish o por simplemente cerrar la app. La activity se reconstruye con valores pre guardados en el objeto `Bundle`, que va a servir para recuperar los datos que van a inflar esa Activity de nuevo.

> Para guardar datos adicionales acerca del estado de la actividad,
>   debes reemplazar el método de devolución de llamada
>   onSaveInstanceState(). El sistema llama a este método cuando el
>   usuario está abandonando tu actividad y le pasa el objeto Bundle que
>   se guardará en caso de que tu actividad se destruya de forma
>   inesperada. Si más posteriormente el sistema debe volver a crear la
>   instancia de la actividad, este pasa el mismo objeto Bundle a los
>   métodos onRestoreInstanceState() y onCreate().

Hint de codigo provisto por la documentación

Para guardar información de estado adicional de tu actividad, debes implementar `onSaveInstanceState()` y agregar pares clave-valor al objeto Bundle. Por ejemplo:

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

A continuación se muestra cómo puedes restaurar cierta información de estado en `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}
```

Para pasar una variable String nueva a la activity que quieres volver a ver, solo usa [putExtra()](http://jonsegador.com/2012/02/paso-de-datos-variables-entre-actividades-android/)

Espero te sirva.